# Change a tab's DOM from Event Page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I have an `Event Page`, in which I set some listeners to find out when user changed the URL in the current tab, using:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    myFunction(tab);
});
```

Now, I want to change some parts of the tab's `DOM`, in using `myFunction`.
I have tested it a bit, and it seems that the `DOM` I am currently changing, it's not the same as the tab's, that user has changed.

I 'm kinda new on this, and I don't know if I have to use `Content Scripts`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking how to change the tab's DOM, I would use a content script for that. Then use `postMessage` to communicate between your event page and your content script if you need to, but event pages can disappear, so that may not be a reliable channel.

This is from the [Google Code documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html):

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
                           {code:"document.body.bgColor='red'"});
});
```

If you are asking how to get the current tab, getting the current tab can vary depending on the context. Below is what has worked for me recently.

In the popup.html for a browser action I have:

```
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
      var current;
      if (_.isEmpty(tabs)) {
        return;
      }
      current = tabs[0];
   });
```

And in a chrome-extention:// I use:

```
   chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab) {
   });
```

Comment: thanks for answering! I Got the tab from JS(at event page). I am just trying to change the DOM from the event page. Is it impossible to do it from there?

Comment: Yes, use a content script, because of security reasons the powerful JavaScript environment in your event page cannot directly interact with a web page's DOM. See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html and https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html

Comment: Also if you find my answer helpful, please don't forget to upvote or mark it as the answer. That may also get you additional answers because it goes back on the home page sometimes.

Comment: I will read the links tomorrow(hopefully), and I will review your answer Bjorn! ;) for now, thanks for the help!